# java.security.KeyStoreException: Failed to delete entry: aliasname at KeyStore.deleteEntry(String)

Tags: java, android, keystore

I see these exceptions occurring for my production users but I can't reproduce it.  It's causing a bunch of other errors that end in an unrecoverable exception and the app crashes.

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("keystorename");
keyStore.load(null);
keyStore.deleteEntry("aliasname");//throws java.security.KeyStoreException: Failed to delete entry: aliasname
```

Is there a way to reproduce this by manually corrupting the keystore, or something similar?

Here is the (slightly redacted/obfuscated) stack trace:

```
com.myapp.exception.WrappedException: java.security.KeyStoreException: Failed to delete entry: aliasname 
at com.myapp.ClassOne.someErrorReportingMethod(ClassOne.java:161) 
at com.myapp.ClassOne.exitMethod(ClassOne.java:135) 
at com.myapp.ClassThree.someOtherMethod(ClassThree.java:51) 
at com.myapp.ClassTwo$ClassTwoImpl.something(ClassTwo.java:313) 
at com.myapp.ClassTwo$ClassTwoImpl.removeKey(ClassTwo.java:281) 
at com.myapp.ClassTwo$ClassTwoImpl.someOtherThing_aroundBody2(ClassTwo.java:225) 
at com.myapp.ClassTwo$ClassTwoImpl$AjcClosure3.run(ClassTwo.java:1) 
at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149) 
at com.myapp.ClassThree.someOtherMethod(ClassThree.java:47) 
at com.myapp.ClassTwo$ClassTwoImpl.initCipher(ClassTwo.java:225) 
at com.myapp.ClassTwo.initCipher(ClassTwo.java:57) 
at com.myapp.ClassFour.confirmFingerprint_aroundBody0(ClassFour.java:68) 
at com.myapp.ClassFour$AjcClosure1.run(ClassFour.java:1) 
at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149) 
at com.myapp.ClassThree.someOtherMethod(ClassThree.java:47) 
at com.myapp.ClassFour.confirmFingerprint(ClassFour.java:33) 
at com.myapp.ClassFive.showFingerprintConfirmDialog(ClassFive.java:485) 
at com.myapp.ClassFive.unrelatedThing(ClassFive.java:352) 
at com.myapp.ClassFive.access$800(ClassFive.java:70) 
at com.myapp.ClassFive$4$1.onSubscribe(ClassFive.java:638) 
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableSubscribeOn.subscribeActual(CompletableSubscribeOn.java:36) 
at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:2185) 
at com.myapp.app.login.AnotherUnrelatedClass.start(AnotherUnrelatedClass.java:55) 
at com.myapp.ClassFive$4.onComplete(ClassFive.java:635) 
at com.myapp.AbstractCompletableTask.onComplete(AbstractCompletableTask.java:34) 
at com.myapp.SomeManager$1.onComplete(SomeManager.java:101) 
at com.myapp.SomeManager$2.onComplete(SomeManager.java:200) 
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated(ObservableObserveOn.java:287) 
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:172) 
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:255) 
at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:119) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Failed to delete entry: aliasname 
at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineDeleteEntry(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:911) 
at java.security.KeyStore.deleteEntry(KeyStore.java:1257) 
at com.myapp.ClassTwo$ClassTwoImpl.removeKey(ClassTwo.java:279) ... 33 more
```

Comment: its there a stacktrace for this exception?

Comment: @Naya just added it

Comment: Doesn't help anyway)) I expected to see cause here

Comment: Does the alias exist?

Comment: it's unclear if the alias exists. i traced it all the way down to a RemoteException thrown in KeyStore, which I believe checked for the presence of the alias. i'll try simulating it

Comment: Running into the same exception in crash reports and can't reproduce the issue. The exception does not appear to be thrown if the alias does not exist. Was any headway ever made on this?

Comment: @Landon, no.  I couldn't even find the source code that would line up to the stack trace. But crash wasn't unique to any combination of carriers, devices, models, or operating system versions.